# In C: Can I have two pointers of different types pointing to the same address?

Tags: c, pointers, utf-8

Question:

Can I have two pointers of different types (`uint32_t *` and `char *`) pointing to the very same address?

---

Here is why I want to have this:

I want to convert [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) to [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) and vice versa in `C`.

Lets say, I have a variable of type `uint32_t` that contains one UTF-32 encoded unicode character. And I already know that it needs 4 byte when encoded in UTF-8. It's binary representation is this:

```
00000000000aaabbbbbbccccccdddddd
```

a, b, c and d are 4 different ranges where each bit can be 0 or 1.
With clever bitwise `&`, `|` and `<<` operations I can rearrange these bits so that at the end there is this new distribution:

```
00000aaa00bbbbbb00cccccc00dddddd
```

And then I can flip some bits (using `|` again), to get this

```
11110aaa10bbbbbb10cccccc10dddddd
```

When I split this into 4 subsequent `char` variables in an array I have this:

```
11110aaa  10bbbbbb  10cccccc  10dddddd
```

which is exactly the UTF-8 encoding of the same unicode character.

So, the very same 4 byte in memory shall be one single `uint32_t` variable and at the same time an array of 4 `char` variables:

So, I want to have this:

```
uint32_t *utf32;
char utf8[4];
```

- `*utf32` is a pointer that points to a single 4 bytes long `uint32_t` variable.
- `utf8` is a pointer to an array of 4 `char` elements, each 1 byte long.

And I want that both pointers point to the very same address. So I can write a utf32 encoded character into the variable `utf32`, transform it in place, and then read the result form the array `utf32`. Is this possible? If so: How can I do it?

(I used this technique very often when I was coding in COBOL in the previous millennium, because in COBOL it's easy to overload the same region in the memory with many different definitions. But I don't know how to do it in C.)

---

I have found a lot of questions dealing with 2 pointers pointing to the same address, but in these questions the pointers have always the same type. And some other questions are about why you get an error if a pointer defined with a certain type points to an address that was defined with another type. But I didn't find anything about two pointers of different types sharing the same address.

Comment: "*So, the very same 4 byte in memory shall be one single `uint32_t` variable and at the same time an array of 4 `char` variables*" - while that is certainly *possible* (by using a `union`, or 2 typed pointers to the same memory, as you ask), I wouldn't suggest doing that. `uint32_t` has endianess, the order of its bytes may not match up with the order you need for the `char[]`. I would use a separate `char[]` and shift bits from the `uint32_t` into the `char[]` as needed regardless of endian. Also, because UTF-8 is variable-length anyway, not all `uint32_t` values will fill a `char[4]`.

Comment: You can do this — but it helps a lot that one of your two pointers will be `char *`.  If you had two pointers neither of which was `char *` — say, `int *` and `float *` — you'd have to worry about [*strict aliasing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650).  But accessing via a `char` type is an explicit exception to that rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I have two pointers of different types (uint32_t * and char *) pointing to the very same address?

Yes, you can.

```
union U {
  uint32_t ui32;
  char c[4];
};

union U u;
u.ui32 = ...

uint32_t *pi = &u.ui32;
char *cp = u.c;

assert(pi == cp);
```

There are some C language rules which you'll violate IF you use the resulting `char*` to do something other than copying the data in or out, but the "two diffierent pointer types pointing to the same address" is not a problem in itself.

You could also simply cast the address to desired type:

```
uint32_t x;
uint32_t *ip = &x;
char *cp = (char*)&x;

assert(ip == cp);
```

Comment: While `union` works, is not necessary. If stored memory is of type `uint32_t` (or compatible) simply casting its pointer to `char*` will do.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, two pointers of different types can point to the same address.**

Let's say that somewhere in your memory is this utf32 and you know where that is so I will refer to this as `address`.

So if you'd want to treat these 4 bytes like a `uint32` you could do this:

```cpp
uint32_t* utf32 = address;
```

And you can just as easily treat is as a char array:

```cpp
char* utf8 = address;
```

If you then want to access a char you just do:

```cpp
utf8[index]
```